# Convert ordinary 'like' to OpenGraph object

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I've been working on a small project with Facebook like buttons and I've run into a small problem.

Suppose I have a web page and I do the following:

- Put a 'like' button on that page ([as described in the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/))

  - ...Without including the OpenGraph meta tags
- I 'like' the page
- I examine the associated OpenGraph object (via http://graph.facebook.com/?id=SITE_NAME).

In this case, I get something like this:

```
{
    "id": "http://my-page/path",
    "shares": 1
}
```

However, if I later add the OpenGraph tags, I still get the same result, even though it should look like an actual OpenGraph object. E.g.

```
{
   "id": "100559863426647",
   "name": "Page",
   "picture": "http://path-to-image.jpg",
   "link": "http://my-url/path",
   "likes": 1,
   "app_id": 392482400810748,
   "category": "Product/service",
   "is_published": true,
   "description": "Some Description",
   "about": "&nbsp;Llama #2"
}
```

**What way is there to take an existing 'liked' URL and convert/correct it into an OpenGraph object, if any?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook needs to rescrape your page before it will get the updated metadata.  That may be the issue.

To get Facebook to rescrape the page, you'll either need to visit the page with [Facebook's Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) or 'Like' the page as the page admin.

More details are available in the "Editing Meta Tags" section of 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this does not work. I have both visited the URL in the linter as well as liked the page as the page admin to no avail. I believe that updating the meta tags only works if the object was an OpenGraph object in the first place.

Comment: Scratch that: I had forgotten who that administrator was, and that seems to have done it. Thanks :)

Comment: I should clarify that 'liking' as the administrator works, but not reparsing the page...